# Extracting specific data from a Mutable Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a Mutable Dictionary which allows people to choose a selection of days of the week. Once a day has been selected the state is updated using numberWithBool.

When I NSLog the output it looks something like this:

```
    {
    day = Monday;
    isSelected = 1;
},
    {
    day = Tuesday;
    isSelected = 0;
},
    {
    day = Wednesday;
    isSelected = 0;
},
    {
    day = Thursday;
    isSelected = 0;
},
    {
    day = Friday;
    isSelected = 0;
},
    {
    day = Saturday;
    isSelected = 0;
},
    {
    day = Sunday;
    isSelected = 1;
}
```

I would like to be able to extract the chosen days and produce the output in the form of a string. So in this example the output would be: Monday, Sunday

How can I do this?

My code for creating the dictionary is below:

```
NSMutableArray * tempSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *daysOfWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday", @"Sunday",nil];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    NSString *dayOfWeek = [daysOfWeek objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dayOfWeek, @"day",   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"isSelected",nil];
    [tempSource addObject:dict];
}

[self setSourceArray:tempSource];
[tempSource release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop thru all of your items in the array and build a side-array only containing names of the day (1), or you can use a predicate and then KVC to extract the days directly (2).

Then join the components of the filtered array into a string.

Solution 1:

```
NSMutableArray selectedDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary* entry in sourceArray)
{
    if (([entry objectForKey:@"isSelected"] boolValue]) {
        [selectedDays addObject:[entry objectForKey:@"day"]];
    }
}
NSString days = [selectedDays componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
[selectedDays release];
```

Solution 2:

```
NSPredicate* filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.isSelected == 1"]; // not sure about the exact format (no mac here to test right now so you may adapt a bit if it does not work directly)
// get the array of dictionaries but only the ones that have isSelected==1
NSArray selectedEntries = [sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter]; 
NSArray selectedDays = [selectedEntries valueForKey:@"day"]; // extract the "days" keys of the dictionaries. We have a NSArray of strings then.
NSString days = [selectedDays componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

---

As a side note, your way of doing this is quite strange. Why having an NSArray of NSDictionaries for this? As this is simple and a static-size array containing only BOOL, you may instead for this particular case simply use C array `BOOL selected[7]` and nothing more.

Then to have the name of the weekdays you should instead use the methods of `NSCalendar`/`NSDateFormatter`/`NSDateComponents` to get the standard names of the weekdays (automatically in the right language/locale of the user): *create an `NSDate` using a `NSDateComponent` for which you simply define the weekday component, then use an `NSDateFormatter` to convert this to a string, choosing a string format that only display the weekday name.*

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  // selectedDays is an instance variable in .h declared as
  // BOOL selectedDays[7];
  selectedDays[indexPath.row] = ! selectedDays[indexPath.row];
  [tv reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  static NSString* kCellIdentifier = @"DayCell";
  UITableViewCell* cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:... identifier:kCellIdentifier]; autorelease];
    // configure here every property that is common to all for your cells (text color, etc)
  }

  // configure here things that will change from cell to cell
  cell.accessoryType = selectedDays[indexPath.row] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeCheckmarck : UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeNone;
  cell.textLabel.text = weekdayName(indexPath.row);

  return cell;
}

// Simple C function to return the name of a given weekday
NSString* weekdayName(int weekday)
{
#if WAY_1
  /**** Solution 1 ****/
  // Optimization note: You may compute this once for all instead of recomputing it each time
  NSDateComponents* comp = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
  [comp setWeekday:weekday+1]; // weekdays start at 1 for NSDateComponents
  NSDate* d = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comp];

  NSDateFormatter* df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; // format for the weekday
  return [[df stringFromDate:d] capitalizedString];
#else
  /**** Solution 2 ****/
  NSDateFormatter* df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  NSArray* weekdayNames = [df weekdaySymbols]; // or maybe one of its sibling methods? check what is returned here to be sure
  return [weekdayNames objectAtIndex:weekday];
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I used Solution 2 and it worked perfectly. This code is used to keep track of which selections have a check mark next to them on a table view. I am quite new to iphone programming and was advised that using an NSArray of NSDictionaries was a good way to do it. I can cetainly see the benefit of using the NSDateComponents to get standard names and will definitely look into this.

Comment: Actually generally an `NSArray` of objects is a good way to manage objects you then display in a `UITableView` that's right. If the number of objets (= rows in your tableview) is dynamic/non-constant, using an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` may be a good solution. **But** going thru the `NSArray` methods (`objetAtIndex`/`setObject:atIndex:`) **AND** thru embedding `BOOL` values into an `NSNumber` is quite painful and **as you have a constant number of cells/days** (always 7) it may be easier for you to manipulate a C array `BOOL selected[7]` instead of a `NSArray` of `NSNumber` embedding `BOOL`s.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what you are saying makes sense, I will certainly have a look at doing it the way you suggest

Comment: Edited to add complete example/solution using C array of `BOOL` + computation of weekday name. (Not tested on a real Mac anyway, may have some typo)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you avoid `NSMutableIndexSet`?

It may simplify your code to:

```
NSArray *daysOfWeek = ...;
NSMutableIndexSet *indexesOfSelectedDays = ...;
NSArray *selectedDays = [daysOfWeek objectsAtIndexes:indexesOfSelectedDays];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSPredicate to create a predicate that selects the items in the array where `isSelected` is true, and use that to filter the array using NSArray's `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method. (@Miraaj posted a good example of using a predicate faster than I could type it.) Then take that filtered array and pick out the days, like this:

```
NSArray *selectedItems = [sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:somePredicate];
NSArray *days = [selectedItems valueForKey:@"day"];
NSString *daysString = [days componentsJoinedByString@", "];
```